# mysql server is failing to get installed to my machine

Tags: mysql

help guys i recently uninstalled my mysql fom my linux machine, im trying to reinstall it it gives me an error message

E: Unable to locate package mysql-server

even if i try the

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

i get the same error

what could have gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the package you are looking for is indeed `mysql-server`.

`dpkg -l 'mysql*'` should list possible candidates.

Otherwise what are your packages sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and which Ubuntu version are your running?